# Android Adding headers to RecyclerView does not display all list items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add headers to columns of RecyclerView list. All list items are not getting displayed when I add headers. Please find the relevant code below:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return (myList == null)? 0 : myList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (myList.get(position) == null) return -1;
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return ItemType.HEADER.getTypeCode();
    else
        return ItemType.ITEM.getTypeCode();
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

if (holder instanceof myListViewHolder) {
            ((myListViewHolder) 
holder).bindData(myList.get(position-1));
}
else if (holder instanceof myHeaderViewHolder){
     Log.d("RecyclerAdapter", "Setting Headers");
}
// Rest of the code
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (viewType == ItemType.ITEM.getTypeCode()) {
        return new 
myListViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false),
                callback);
    }
    else if (viewType == ItemType.HEADER.getTypeCode()) {
            return new 
myHeaderViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_header_item, parent, false),
                    callback);
    }
    else {
        return new LoadViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading_view, 
parent, false));
    }
}

protected Profile getItemByPosition(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (getItemByPosition(position) == null) return -1;
    return getItemByPosition(position).getId().hashCode();
}
```

With the above code, the headers are displayed at the zeroth position, next the list items are displayed leaving the last item i.e. if list has 5 elements, only 4 elements are getting displayed.
I have tried to return myList.size() +1 in getItemCount(), but this throws an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed you've not implemented `createViewHolder` as seen in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#createViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int). That helps RecyclerView determine whether to use the header or list item view holder.

It would seem that the `getItemCount` method is implemented incorrectly - it needs to be the number of headers + number of items.

Then fix the method like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return ItemType.HEADER.getTypeCode();
    else {
        if(myList.get(position - 1) == null){
            return -1;
        }  
        else {
            return ItemType.ITEM.getTypeCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add onCreateViewHolder in the post, have edited it. When I return myList.size() + 1 from getItemsCount(), it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException and app crashes.

Comment: I think the line of code that's the culprit is if (myList.get(position) == null) return -1; If you have 5 items meaning 1 header and 4 items, and your getItemCount is returning 5, myList.get(4) will be called, and there's no such element, only 0 to 3.

Comment: My list has 6 elements and with header the total item count is 7. I removed the line if (myList.get(position) == null) return -1;. Also tried if(myList.get(position - 1) == null){
            return -1; }  that you mentioned in the above code. But it still does not display the last element in the list.

Comment: Have you updated your getItemCount method to be myList's length + 1? Are any of the items in the list null?

Comment: No null items in the list. Yes, I have tried returning myList.size() + 1. It throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 from method getItemByPosition() . I know this is because of the header row at position 0. But how do I handle this exception?

Comment: That's because there are have 7 positions (0 to 6) that ```getItemId``` will be called with. But there are only 6 elements in ```myList```. Whenever you access myList for positions 1 to 6, use position - 1, but if position is 0, is it the header and you have to handle it separately.